# Tensorflow LSTM post training example. How to store a 'rnn_cell' in memory?

Tags: tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network, lstm

There are many examples online of people successfully training their LSTM model, but I can't find ANYTHING on how to use the 'state' returned from the tf.nn.rnn() function to actually run the model on new data, without training.  I want to actually use the magic numbers discovered by my training!  How do I do this?

Consider this code:

```
nval, state_ = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(nstacked_lstm, xData, initial_state=newStateP, dtype=tf.float32)
```

I can tell you FOR SURE that 'xData' and 'newStateP' are exactly the same everytime I run this code, yet I get different values every time for both 'nval' and 'state_' ....  so it has to be something with the rnnCell I'm passing in, in this case it's 'nstacked_lstm'.  I thought that instantiating an rnnCell was more like making a placeholder, but apparently it has data in it.  How can I pass in the same rnnCell over and over?  and also, how can I save it on my computer?  It's not an array or string, so I really don't know how to to store it.

I'm really at a loss here.  Someone please help!!!

**EDIT**  I never could figure this out with the tf.nn.dynamic_rnn() type of functions that TF had.... but I was able to find a tutorial floating around online that broke this function out in a more 'by hand' way, allowing you to store all the variables.  Here is a jupyter notebook that shows the LSTM function and allows you to use previously-trained variables if you want.

[predict_functions_with_LSTM_RNN](https://github.com/rikkitikkitumbo/stock_machine_learning/blob/master/predict_functions_with_LSTM_RNN.ipynb)

Answer (score 0):

Either you have not worded your question properly or you are not clear on how to "train" a neural network and then "predict" using the trained model.

When you "train" the model, you pass your data through the RNN, get the output, and then backpropagate the gradient from your loss over the RNN parameters. That way, these parameters get adjusted to fit your data.

Once you have this trained model, you can pass new data through the RNN network (using `rnn.rnn`) and use the output (`nval` in your case) to produce your actual output (using softmax for example, similar to how you had obtained the output while training).

That's about as terse as I could get.

As for getting the same value, you will probably have to set the seed for the graph. Otherwise, the parameters (weights) of RNN (initialized in the function `_linear`) would be initialized using the default initializer for that variable scope.

The state returned by `rnn.rnn()` comes into play only if you decide to use that state to initialize the state of a another RNN (for example).

TensorFlow also provides functionality to save your model. Check out `tf.train.Saver()` for more details.

I would advise you to go through the tutorials up on their site, specially on RNN, to get a better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the `state` of your RNN is not the trained weights and biases that you get out, it is the activations of every layer of your RNN on the last input that it saw. The `state_history` is the output of the last layer of your RNN for all inputs that it saw in the given batch. To see the actual weights and biases of your network, use:

```py
with tf.Session as sess:
    vars = tf.trainable_variables()
    for var in vars:
        print(var.name)  # the name of the variable
        print(sess.run(var))  # its value
```

To restore your RNN and work with it later, you need to first create a [saver and save your model](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.0/programmers_guide/variables) after it is finished training. The pseudo-code implementation looks like this:

```py
saver = tf.train.Saver()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    # ... Initialize code ...
    # ... Run training process ...
    # Note it is a good idea to save your session at each best validation.
    saver.save(sess, SAVE_PATH)  # assuming SAVE_PATH is something you have set
```

Then let's say you want to restore this model in another session some time later and do some predicting. To do that, you create another saver and use it to [restore the metagraph from your checkpoint](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.0/programmers_guide/meta_graph).

```py
with tf.Session as sess:
    new_saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('/path/to/meta_graph.meta')
    new_saver.restore(sess, SAVE_PATH)
    # ... Use your ops ...
```

The tricky part comes in making your ops available in your restored session. To do this, add whatever ops you want available to collections in your training script:

```py
tf.add_to_collection('predict_op', model.predict_op)
tf.add_to_collection('error_op', model.error_op)
# etc.
```

And then restore them in your restored session with:

```py
predict_op = tf.get_collection('predict_op')[0]  # returns an array, we want the first element
error_op = tf.get_collection('error_op')[0]
_, error = sess.run([predict_op, error_op], feed_dict=feed_dict)
# etc.
```

I recall there being one further wrinkle when I had to figure this out, but my notebook is being a pain and not loading. When I figure out what it was I will update my answer.

**Edit:** I remember now! It can be a pain finding tensors that you want to find in the metagraph unless you specify names for them when you train the network. For any tensor/operation that is not an intermediate operation that you really don't care about looking at later, make sure you specify `name=` parameter when you create the op. Then you can restore these named tensors with (assuming you named your predict_op "prediction" and your error_op "error"):

```py
prediction = tf.get_tensor_by_name('prediction:0')
error = tf.get_tensor_by_name('error:0')
```

Depending on your use case, one of these approaches might work better than the other. You should try both and see what works for you.